# tmux logging for all windows and all panes

Tags: logs, tmux

***tldr;:*** *I’m trying to figure out how to start logging in tmux and have it do it for every new window I create and for every pane within those windows.*

I just got into tmux and was looking for a way to log I/O in tmux.

I’m struggling on understanding how to log every window and every pane during a session.I know the keybinding to start logging and have that setup:

`bind-key H pipe-pane -o "exec cat >>$HOME/'#S-#I-#P-tmux.log'" \; display-message 'Started logging to $HOME/#W-tmux.log'`

`bind-key h pipe-pane \; display-message 'Ending logging to $HOME/#W-tmux.log'`

But it seems that for every new window and for every pane I create within a window (vertical or horizontal) I’d have to start logging in each of those. That feels like a lot of manual steps.

I’m trying to figure out how to start logging and have it do it for every new window I create and for every pane within those windows.

Is that possible? I know that GNU Screen has the `deflog on` setting which will log all new windows and I'm hoping for something similar.
Maybe I’m asking for too much from an automated perspective and it has to be manual.

Thank you for your time in looking over this question.